# Icon on top of another icon in Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-maps-markers, android-icons

I'm coding an android app (using java) maps-like and I use two kind of markers from Google Maps SKD: one for my current position, the other one indicates me places of intereset.

I set two different icons for these markers, how can I give to one of them the priority?
I want mu current position icon marker to be shown over all other icon markers, how can I do that?

Thank you for time :)

EDIT: here's some code I'm using for my current position marker

```
        Drawable arrowDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.current_position_icon);
        BitmapDescriptor arrowIcon = getMarkerIconFromDrawable(arrowDrawable);

        Marker currentPositionMarker = gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()))
                .draggable(false)
                .rotation(location.getBearing())
                .icon(arrowIcon)
                .flat(true));
```

And here's some code I'm using to set my other markers

```
    Marker marker = gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(event.getLatitude(), event.getLongitude()))
            .title("Acc. value -> " + Double.toString(event.getAccelerometerValue()))
            .icon(potholeIcon)
            .draggable(false));
```

It's the only time where I use my markers, I don't use it im my XML or in other Java code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Render your "current position icon" after you rendered every other icon.

If it's XML then just add it last.

If it's in Java then just declare and add it to the layout last.

Can't provide code if you can't provide code though...

Edit:

Made out my mind, I'll provide some code.

XML:

```
    <Layout...>
        <Other_Icon.../>
        <Other_Icon.../>
        <Other_Icon.../>
        <Your_Current_Position.../>
    </Layout...>
```

Or

Java:

```
    Layout layout=new Layout(...);
    //A lot of other icons...
    layout.addView(icon1);
    layout.addView(icon2);
    layout.addView(icon3);
    //Your position icon...
    layout.addView(your_current_position_icon);
```

Or, if you are using drag-and-drop.

Just drop the icon last.

(But it would be better if you code it instead just to make sure.)

Comment: I'm sorry, adding some code would have been better for sure, my mistake.

Thank you for your patience, I edited my question.

The fact is that I use my icons on Google Maps Markers, and I want the "current position" one to have priority on others.

Comment: @lookatviki It's still the same principle, just declare and render it last, this works no matter what situation it is or no matter how specific it is.

Comment: rendering and declering it first but still showing the current position under all other icons.
Anyway, thanks for helping

Comment: @lookatviki It seems as if we do not understand each other on this topic, you have to render it "LAST", not "FIRST" so that it will render "ABOVE" everything else, by what you have said, you have not tried my solution yet. Tell me if it had not worked for you.